# Return rows where no match is found in another table

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Couldn't find a question that had this exact problem.

I have 2 tables, I want to return the rows from one table where the row doesn't exist in the second table.

I will make an example to show.

The first table:

**teamName**
United 
Athletic 
Football 
Rugby

The second table:
**Username         team** 
Gary                       United 
Gary                       United 
Phil                       Rugby 
Phil                       Rugby

So what I want to do is select all the teams from the first table that don't appear in the second table. However the problem is I want only want it to compare against the rows where the Username is Gary.

So selecting all the rows from the first table where the team name does not exist in the second table and the username is Gary for example.

I managed to pull all the rows where the team name does not exist in the second table via a left join, however I am not sure how to add the condition where the username equals something.

I realise I may have to change the structure of my tables. I am open to suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` clause to find the teams that is not present in `table2`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   teams t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   userteams ut
                   WHERE  t.teamname = ut.teamname
                          AND ut.name = 'Gary')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find all teams that don't have a player named Gary, using a `left outer join`:

```
select t.*
from teams t left join
     userteams ut
     on t.teamname = ut.teamname and ut.name = 'Gary'
where ut.username is null;
```